# Can clang-format act differently based on the presence of braces?

Tags: c, clang-format

I'd like `clang-format` to change:

```c
if (condition) { printf("%d\n", 0); }
```

to:

```c
if (condition) {
    printf("%d\n", 0);
}
```

This happens if I set `AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine` to `Never`. However, I'd also like the following to be possible:

```c
if (condition) return;
```

In other words, I'd like `clang-format` to force a separate line only in the presence of braces. With `AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: Never`, this gets changed to:

```c
if (condition)
    return;
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You need to set `AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine` to `false`. Then set `AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine` to `WithoutElse` or `Always` (or `true`, for versions of `clang-format` before 10.0).

When the code has braces, the `AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine` setting is used. When the code has no braces, the `AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine` setting is used. See the [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) for more details.

A good place to experiment with style settings like this is the [configurator](https://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator/).